# Stop Windows voice recorder and google meet to capture my system's audio

Tags: windows, windows-10

I can't figure it out why my voice recorder and google meet in chrome capturing my computer's audio too like youtube video running in the background. I have Realtek audio console installed too and have b550 aorus elite motherboard.

Edit:
When I record my voice via voice recorder app in windows, only mic input should be captured and when I am using goole meet and turn on mic in google meet by clicking on red mic icon button, it should only capture my voice input via microphone. Instead its also capturing computer's audio such as youtube playing in another tab (You have to see some funny memes if meeting is long and boring)
Also I am using only headphones, not loud speakers. Stereo mix option is also disabled in sound settings.

**PROBLEM IS SOLVED NOW BY REINSTALLING THE WINDOWS**

Comment: This question is a scrambled mess.  The first sentence is mostly incoherent by the time you get to the youtube video part.  Can you break this question up and make it more readable?  How do you know that your audio is being "captured"?  What does youtube have to do with anything.  People can help you more if you make this question better. :)  I don't mean to discourage you.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I know because one of my co worker on google meet told me turn of mic when I was watching youtube. Before this, I usually turns off the mic via microphone button on my headphones. When I checked voice recorder app, it was also capturing youtube's audio playing in google chrome.